# How to remove FilteringScheme using C# API?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I am trying to figure out how to remove a FilteringScheme from the API. I was looking at the C# API but couldn't find a delete or remove method. The code below adds one but I am having trouble how to delete one after I add it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
// Add a new data filtering selection.
DataFilteringSelection dataFilteringSelection = document.Data.Filterings.Add("Filtering Scheme1");
// A filtering scheme has now been implicitly added for the new data filtering selection.
FilteringScheme myFilteringScheme = document.FilteringSchemes[dataFilteringSelection];
// Let the active page use the new filtering scheme.
document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel.FilteringSchemeReference = myFilteringScheme;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do that thanks to the TIBCO community [answer](https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-remove-filteringscheme-using-c-api#node-1095431). This is what I needed to do:

```
foreach (var fs in Document.FilteringSchemes)
{
    if (fs.FilteringSelectionReference.Name == "Georgi")
    {
        context.Document.Data.Filterings.Remove(fs.FilteringSelectionReference);
    }
}
```